# How to test for the EOF flag in R?

Tags: r, file, file-io, eof

How can I test for the `EOF` flag in R?

For example:

```
f <- file(fname, "rb")
while (???) {
    a <- readBin(f, "int", n=1)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The [readLines](http://wiki.r-project.org/rwiki/doku.php?id=rdoc:base:readlines) function will return a zero-length value when it reaches the EOF.

Answer (score 5):

Try checking the length of data returned by readBin:

```
while (length(a <- readBin(f, 'int', n=1)) > 0) {
    # do something
}
```